# Neo4j - Returning a Collection object in JSON in an unmanaged extension

Tags: json, neo4j

I've written an unmanaged extension for Neo4j and I need it to return a Collection(I have a Set) and wanted to return it in JSON, but when I try to return the object I get

```
SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type class java.util.ArrayList, and MIME media type application/json was not found
Aug 14, 2012 8:56:51 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse write
SEVERE: The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General

javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.util.HashSet, and Java type class java.util.HashSet, and MIME media type application/json was not found
```

My Java code is

```
Set<Long> matches = new HashSet<Long>();
return Response.ok(matches, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
```

I assume that it would handle lists, but from the error above I can see it doesn't. Is this possible in Neo4j unmanaged extensions

Comment: try to make it a list before you pass it in, weird though.

Comment: I get the same error when I attempt to use an ArrayList. I added the MIME types it says are available to the question.

Comment: So I got it working in a way. If I take my set and return it as a String, but with a @Produces of JSON, it returns it as a JSON list. But I would still like to know of a way to have it handle say a Custom Object I might make.